# How to use different versions of the same gradle dependency in different Android Studio modules?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my Android Studio project, I have two modules *app* and *library*.
Therefore I also have two *build.gradle* files.

build.gradle(app):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    ...
}
```

build.gradle(library):

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    ...
}
```

When I call some retrofit methods in my *library* module, it uses okhttp 2.4.0 instead of 2.3.0. Why is this the case and how can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit most likely has a transitive dependency on `okhttp` and uses `2.4.0`.

You might try

```
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'){
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'}
```

to force retrofit to use the `okhttp` dependency that you declared yourself. 
I don't know though if Retrofit relies on a certain version / implementation of OkHttp and will work properly if it is changed.

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the client? https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/467

Comment: downvoted for not responding to the general question, but providing a workaround for the particular problem

Comment: @J.K. I did explain why this happens and offered a way to solve the problem. OP failed to explain why he thinks my approach doesn't work. Neither did you btw.